# Android Emulator in Aptana Studio3

Tags: aptana

Can I run the Android SDK emulators for Android website testing in Aptana Studio 3?
Do I need to install the Eclipse plugin?
I have installed Android SDK, and use Aptana Studio 3, but I am not sure if they will work together. 
Thanks in advance
Ant

Comment: did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a major conflict by installing both plugins into Eclipse.

Aptana Studio's 'younger brother', Titanium Studio, can run both, so no real reason why the studio wouldn't run both as well.

In any case, if you stumble into issues like that, you can open a ticket at http://jira.appcelerator.org/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa